# Using svn in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to Use svn, for subversioning. Can i use any machine as a repository on the LAN or just the one which is Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install SVN server on any machine.

However it would be easier to use some service that offers svn, because installing and administrating it is not always straightforward. If it's no problem for you make your project open-source, you can use [Google code](https://code.google.com/projecthosting/) or [SourceForge](http://sf.net). If you need a private repository See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories, there you can find some private repositories

Since you've tagged eclipse, in order to use SVN in eclipse, you need [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) or [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/).

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to any subversion server you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a SVN repository on any machine. SVN doesn't really require a server, but your users must be able to access the machine, e.g. with ssh or Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of your desired clients can see the repository machine through the relevant port, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any machine that is running the server software, it sounds like you are looking for software like git `http://git-scm.com/`

Answer (score 0):

as long as the server running subversion can access the folder using a direct filepath you should be fine...